# How to create a Crypto wallet for a start up(Bitcoin and Ethereum)?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, library

I have beginner skills as Full stack Developer and am looking to help developing a crypto wallet with a small start up. The idea is to create a wallet that will store our users cryptocurrencies (with a function to send it to a different users or institution). Have you used a specific library and can you recommend one?

Answer (score 4):

> I have beginner skills as Full stack Developer and am looking to help developing a crypto wallet with a small start up.

Building a wallet from scratch is a major endeavor and fraught with security responsibilities. I'd recommend that you instead use an existing wallet or service. You will probably find that getting a small startup off the ground will keep you adequately busy, even if you "only" integrate an existing wallet into your user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoinj is a java bitcoin library that has a wallet class that can be used by any JVM compatible language. Web3.js can be used for Ethereum. I have used both but not for any application done for the mainnet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it and build one like this https://codeamigo.dev/lessons/preview/53